# Регуляка. Инпут только c цифрами и первый символ не 0

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, std-regex

Всем привет!

Вопрос:
Нужно разрешить вводить в инпут только цифры и первая цифра не должна быть 0

Сейчас это так:

```
const str = '012323123a2312sdasf22123gev321d';
const clearedString = str.replace(/^[0|\D]/, '').replace(/\D/g, '')

// 12323123231222123321
```

Всё уже работает!

Но как эти **2 replace** переписать в **один**?

Comment: Может, `.replace(/^[\D0]+/, '')`?

Comment: неа, не получается

Comment: Да, понял. Должно быть `.replace(/^[\D0]+|\D/g, '')`

Comment: У input'a есть type='number'

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/number

Answer (score 5):

Вы можете использовать

```
.replace(/^[\D0]+|\D/g, '')
```

См. [пример работы выражения](https://regex101.com/r/abSqVE/1).

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `[\D0]+` - один и более символов, отличных от цифр, или цифра `0`
- `|` - или
- `\D` - любой символ, отличный от цифры
- `g` - найти все совпадения.

Пример работы кода:

```js
console.log( '012323123a2312sdasf22123gev321d'.replace(/^[\D0]+|\D/g, '') )
```

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо! :)

Comment: @Cuba58 Отметьте ответ как верный, пожалуйста.